# How to add pass route param to url view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I've created routing based on Hostname but reached trouble with URL generation when using `\Zend\View\Helper\Url`.

When I run:

```
$this->url('main/faq')
```

helper creates URL without lang param in subdomain. Ok, I can use:

```
$this->url('main/faq', [], [], true)
```

and then lang param is attached to subdomain, but this call makes a lot of mess (as it keeps other parameters that needed no more).

Is there any solution to attach lang param to subdomain without setting `$reuseMatchedParams`? Or to use it without mess?

Comment: you can make an other helper maybe?

Comment: nvm there's shorthand: http://zendframework.github.io/zend-view/helpers/url/#shorthand